# Netbeans Git Module Shows Files as Ignored but They Are Not

Tags: git, netbeans, gitignore

Netbeans is showing all files and folders under /var/www/application/app/webroot/ as ignored, but that is not what is in the .gitignore file. Any ideas? This is incredibly annoying.

Git version 1.7.9.5

Netbeans version 7.2.1 (Build 201210100934)

Here is the ignore file:

```
Config/database.php
.idea
.DS_Store
Config/Schema/Builds/*.sql
Config/build.properties


Config/Schema/Dumps/*
!Config/Schema/Dumps/empty

# Test URI
# Ignore netbeans folder
nbproject/*

# Ignore private folder
private/*
!private/empty

# Ignore packed asset files
webroot/css/packed/*
!webroot/css/packed/.htaccess
webroot/js/packed/*
!webroot/js/packed/.htaccess

# MAC
.DS_Store

# Windows
Thumbs.db

# Eclipse project files
.cache
.project
.settings
.buildpath

# Cake TMP Dirs
tmp/*
!tmp/

tmp/cache/*
!tmp/cache/empty

tmp/cache/models/*
!tmp/cache/models/
!tmp/cache/models/empty
tmp/cache/views/*
!tmp/cache/views/
!tmp/cache/views/empty

tmp/logs/*
!tmp/logs/empty

tmp/sessions/*
!tmp/sessions/empty

tmp/tests/*
!tmp/tests/empty
```

Comment: does only netbean say that or does git agree?

Comment: what is your output from 'git status' ?

Comment: @sjakubowski Git status output: # modified:   Plugin/AclExtras (modified content)
# modified:   Plugin/Bancha (new commits, modified content)
# modified:   Plugin/BanchaDeveloperRemoteApi (modified content)
# modified:   Plugin/DebugKit (new commits, modified content)
# modified:   Plugin/acl (new commits, modified content)
# modified:   webroot/bancha-scaffold (modified content)

Comment: @Chronial How would I check this? I think only Netbeans thinks this.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Not webroot though, it's a specific folder but everything inside including subfolder contents are greyed out. Just started out of nowhere and super annoying. Git is functioning normally on it's own, it's just netbeans doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer a problem in NetBeans 7.4